Gradle junitXML system-out at wrong position
I use Gradle and Appium for integration tests. I want to upload the generated junit.xml file to an external tool. For this, I need a specific format for my XML file.
Currently, 'system-out' appears after 'testcase'. Instead, 'system-out' should be inside 'testcase'. At the moment, my XML looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite name="de.MyTest" tests="1" skipped="0" failures="0" errors="0" timestamp="2024-06-21T08:19:51" hostname="CP21965" time="51.944">
  <properties/>
  <testcase name="myTestMethod()" classname="de.MyTest" time="51.944"/>
  <system-out>
    LogStatement1
    LogStatement2
    LogStatement3
  </system-out>
</testsuite>

My goal is to have the XML formatted like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite name="de.MyTest" tests="1" skipped="0" failures="0" errors="0" timestamp="2024-06-21T08:19:51" hostname="CP21965" time="51.944">
  <properties/>
  <testcase name="myTestMethod()" classname="de.MyTest" time="51.944">
    <system-out>      
      LogStatement1
      LogStatement2
      LogStatement3
    </system-out>
  </testcase>
</testsuite>

The Question is:
I know the junit.xml is generated by Gradle. Can i configure where system-out is added in my junit.xml?
I searched in Gradle documentation and stack overflow, but found nothing.

doesn't make much sence to me: in one TEST-blah.xml file you can have MULTIPLE <testcase/> elements, but there always be a single <system-out/>.

you can always post-process your reports though via some simple XML read-write task in your build.gradle

yeah I can have multiple , and for each testcase i want to have a seperate system-out.

I have no idea, how Gradle generates those xml fiels, but what you can make pretty painless is splitting your test-classes so that each has a single test case. Than you have 1:1 mapping testcase to system-out, which you easily post-process via gradle.
